# Copy A Cell On Double Click And Paste to A Different Cell on Another Sheet Automatically

Tags: excel, hyperlink, worksheet, double-click

I really need your help.

Basically I have 2 sheets that I really am concerned for my project as pictured below.

1. MUFG Client
2. MUFG Matched

[image]
[image]

I am looking for VBA code that allows me to:

- Double click on a cell within a range (B3:B300) on MUFG Client Sheet.
- On Double clicking, it will take the content of the cell I have double clicked on (could be any cell in the above range) and paste the text/value into a different cell on MUFG Matched sheet (Cell D4) automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried a couple of things such as making hyperlink to the content within the range but it still doesn't work at all and fails too many times.

Thanks

Rendi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following VBA code should work as you described:

```
Option Explicit
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
' returns True if Range1 is within Range2
Dim InterSectRange As Range
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)
    InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
    Set InterSectRange = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InRange(ActiveCell, Worksheets("MUFG Client").Range("B3:B300")) Then
        Selection.Copy Worksheets("MUFG Matched").Range("d4")
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure that you place this code into the **worksheet code area** of *MUFG Client*, since that is where you will be double clicking.

Comment: Hey, this is the answer I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help. Already checked and up vote your answer. Cannot do this without you :D

Comment: I also wanna know in case you can add something in the current VBA code you have given to me if I double-clicked the cell within the range, it will automatically move to MUFG Matched sheet without manually clicking the MUFG Matched Sheet first. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course! If you add the line of code `Worksheets("MUFG Matched").Activate` after `Selection.Copy Worksheets("MUFG Matched").Range("d4")` it will automatically switch your view to MUFG Matched. Happy to help!

Comment: Wow it works! Yessss, Thank you so much once again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Worksheet_BeforedoubleClick` event - look them up if you haven't met worksheet events before.
Then it would be something like;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'Check if it's in the range:
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row <300 And Target.Row >3 Then
    'Copy to relevant location
    Target.Copy Worksheets("MUFG Matched").Range("D4")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I know this technically could get trippy if the `Target` range was larger than a single cell, but it's very difficult if not impossible to double-click on a larger range as such, so this should be safe enough.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your answer. Yes, you're right, we need BeforeDoubleClick event to make this works :)